# errors after gem update --system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, rack-pow

I working on OSX on a ruby on Rails application. Using RVM for managing ruby. I just did:

```
gem update --system
```

I thought this is something you have to do once in a while. But it seems that this has broken something. When I start my application (i am using Pow) I see these errors:

```
Error starting application
Your Rack app raised an exception when Pow tried to run it.

NameError: uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:353:in `stub_rubygems'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:250:in `replace_entrypoints'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'  
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require' ~/Sites/mafticket/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top 
(required)>' ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require' 
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require' ~/Sites/mafticket/config/application.rb:1:in `<top 
(required)>' ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require' 
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require' ~/Sites/mafticket/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top 
(required)>' ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require' 
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require' ~/Sites/mafticket/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval' ~/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize' ~/Sites/mafticket/config.ru:1:in `new' ~/Sites/mafticket/config.ru:1:in 
`<main>' ~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in `eval' ~/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:50:in `load_config' ~/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:43:in `initialize' ~/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `new' ~/Library/Application
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run' ~/Library/Application  
Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Did I something wrong or should I restart something?
Can I undo?

Thanks

Comment: when you install a version of ruby with rvm it will usually install the appropriate version of gem executable and bundler; try running `gem -v` see if you have two versions now? you could try `rvm install rubygems 1.4.2`, change `1.4.2` to the version you want installed

Answer (score 3):

Great feedback, thanks

It looks like I solved my problem by typing:

```
gem update bundler
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `gem update --system` try:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p362
rvm rubygems latest
```

the difference might be that the first command will get `rubygems-2.0`+ and RVM is still keeping `1.8`+ for all rubies except ruby-2.0.0